# What does nl="true" mean in the package-restrictions.xml file?

Tags: applications

When you disable an app using the following command:

```
$ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.android.videos
```

the three attributes will be added to the `/data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml` file:

```
<pkg name="com.google.android.videos" inst="false" stopped="true" nl="true" />
```

I know what `inst="false"` and `stopped="true"` mean, but what does `nl="true"` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nl` implies "not launched". From what I could understand it is used with respect to the state of a component and shows whether the component had ever been started by Android itself. You can check the following links to reach this conclusion:

1. [PackageUserState.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/3ff8e1a80058e5557d13693d3223e1aa011c0038/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageUserState.java#52)
2. [PackageSettingsBase.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/483f3b06ea84440a082e21b68ec2c2e54046f5a6/services/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageSettingBase.java#69)
3. [Settings.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ccbf84f/services/java/com/android/server/pm/Settings.java#108)